# Jupyter notebook code block has [ ] instead of In[1]

Tags: jupyter-notebook

As shown in the picture below,

[image: Screenshot of Jupyter Notebook]

the code blocks in Jupyter show `[ ]` instead of `In[1]`. If I try to run something like `4+4`, I will get no output, and the text next to the code block will change to `[*]`.

I have tried restarting the kernel, which did not work.
If I use `ipython` on the command line, `In[1]` is displayed.

How can I fix this in order to use a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: You are posting about two different things here which is discouraged. The title and first sentence just reference a style issue which I'll come back to. You'd need to supply more information about, "If I try to run something like 4+4". I see your kernel status indicator in the upper right is showing busy. (It is the little circle in the upper right side.) So until that shows clear and not busy, you cannot run code. It probably means you have an issue. Does the place where you kick off Jupyter show any error or anything?

Comment: As to the style issue... See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/complete-noob-and-going-nowhere/23668?u=fomightez) where the OP starts describing that the first cell "only shows two square brackets [ ], it does not show In [ ], as absolutely all youtube videos seem to have, also the tutorial I am following." My reply gets at the situation causing this is the new style in Jupyter Notebook 7+.  I should point out this could actually be related to your inability to run code if you had the older version before & tried updating and it wasn't a successful update.

Comment: If you want the older style that is closer to IPython stylistically, then you are looking for NbClassic which [my reply there](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/complete-noob-and-going-nowhere/23668/2?u=fomightez) discusses. Keep in mind though that if you choose NbClassic you are hanging on to tech that more and more won't match the current generation of Jupyter software. Because you mention IPython, I'll point out that [The Big Split](https://blog.jupyter.org/the-big-split-9d7b88a031a7) came about because of tensions in directions for the original components and what you are seeing with ...

Comment: <continued> the text formerly in front brackets is an example of the outcome of such a split. The more clean view, i.e., leaving off the 'In' in front of the brackets , is possible because the cell concept is more clear in the browser with the box for entering code already apparent. In the more sparse console where IPython runs, it makes more sense to still distinguish clearly the Input part with the bracket prefixed with 'In' and distinguish it from the parallel output.